# How to add more support PWA on GoogleSite

Tags: progressive-web-apps, google-sites

This is the check list from Light house on my site.(made by GoogleSite)
Progressive Web App
These checks validate the aspects of a Progressive Web App, as specified by the baseline PWA Checklist.

```
1
Does not respond with a 200 when offline
2
User will not be prompted to Install the Web App
Failures: No manifest was fetched, Site does not register a service worker.
3
Does not register a service worker
4
Is not configured for a custom splash screen
Failures: No manifest was fetched.
5
Address bar does not match brand colors
Failures: No manifest was fetched, No `<meta name="theme-color">` tag found.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven’t created a manifest or any service workers: the key engine of PWA. Because of this you are not caching assets and they’re can’t be found online, so you can’t get a 200 status (all ok, page found).

From the question, I am assuming a simple static site. The simplest way you could solve this is by going to https://www.pwabuilder.com, imputing your website, and copying the boiler plate code. By the time you finish you will pass the Light House rest and your site will work offline and have all the PWA features.